# sas update column order in metadata

Tags: xml, sas, metadata, sas-metadata

We are using **proc metadata** (open metadata interface) to update some metadata from XML.
Using *updatemetadata* method, how can we achieve the following:

- add a new column to a specific location in the *Columns* association of a given table with the use of the *function="REPLACE"* option (by default, the new column will be the first in the association)

We are using version 9.3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution:
It has to be done in two steps.

In the first step the new column has to be added. Depending on the function you use, it will be either the first or the last column in the table metadata.

In the second step you have to use the function="replace" option with updatemetadata, where the columns are in the desired order.

Example:

In the first updatemetadata block the field TEST_PCT is added to the HBR.TEST_7 table. Because it is added with function="replace", it will be the first column of the table and the old columns will be after that.

So a second updatemetadata block is needed with the proper column order, and because at this point all columns are already existing, it will reorder them properly.

```
<Multiple_Requests>
<UpdateMetadata>
    <Metadata>
        <PhysicalTable  id="A52YJRW0.B30005KO" name="HBR.TEST_7" MemberType="DATA" PublicType="Table"  desc="Test_1_Notes á, é, í, ó, ö, ő, ü, ű" sastablename="TEST_7" UsageVersion="1000000">
            <Columns function="replace">
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J0">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J1">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J2">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J3">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  id="$o601" name="TEST_PCT" desc=" " isnullable="1" PublicType="Column" sascolumnlength="8" sascolumnname="TEST_PCT" SASColumnType="N" SASFormat="COMMAX22.2" SASInformat="COMMAX22.2" UsageVersion="1000000">
                    <Notes>
                        <TextStore Name="PrivateNote"  storedtext=" " TextRole="Note" UsageVersion="0"/>
                    </Notes>
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J5">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J6">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J7">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J8">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J9">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </PhysicalTable>
    </Metadata>
    <Reposid>A0000001.A52YJRW0</Reposid>
    <Type>PhysicalTable</Type>
    <Objects/>
    <NS>SAS</NS>
    <Flags>268435456</Flags>
</UpdateMetadata>
<UpdateMetadata>
    <Metadata>
        <PhysicalTable  id="A52YJRW0.B30005KO" name="HBR.TEST_7" UsageVersion="1000000">
            <Columns function="replace">
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J0">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J1">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J2">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J3">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="$o601">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J5">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J6">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J7">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J8">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
                <Column  objref="A52YJRW0.B80008J9">
                    <Table>
                        <PhysicalTable  objref="A52YJRW0.B30005KO"/>
                    </Table>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </PhysicalTable>
    </Metadata>
    <Reposid>A0000001.A52YJRW0</Reposid>
    <Type>PhysicalTable</Type>
    <Objects/>
    <NS>SAS</NS>
    <Flags>268435456</Flags>
</UpdateMetadata>
```